# mouseover- mouseout/hover/moudeenter-mouseleaves make the to flicker

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, jquery-events, onmouseover

```
<div id="risk-free-logo" style="float:left;margin-left:30px;height:100px;width:100px">
       </div>
 <div id="risk-free-info-div" style="border: 2px solid; display:none; position: relative; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); z-index:         100; height: 170px; width: 300px; margin-left: 150px;" class="popupbox"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#risk-free-logo').mouseenter(
    function(){
          $(this).siblings('.popupbox').css('display','block');
              }); 
    $('#risk-free-logo').mouseleave(
       function(){
         $(this).siblings('.popupbox').css('display','none');
           }   
    );
});
```

Onmouseover I have to show a div. But using any event makes the the flicker

Comment: what do you want to do ...flickering ??

Answer (score 0):

You'v no doubt answered this by now, or found an alternative, so for anyone else who ends up here from Google the following will work flicker-free (I couldn't get your code to work or create the flickering).

In your code replace `$(this).siblings('.popupbox')` with `$('.popupbox')`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
$("#risk-free-logo").mouseenter(function (event) {
    $('.popupbox').css('display','block');
});
$("#risk-free-logo").mouseout(function (event) {
    $('.popupbox').css('display','');
}); 
</script>

<style>
#risk-free-logo {border: 2px solid red; float:left;margin-left:30px;height:100px;width:100px; }
#risk-free-info-div {border: 2px solid; display:none; position: relative; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); z-index:100; height: 170px; width: 300px; margin-left: 150px; }
</style>

<div id="risk-free-logo">Mousenter me to display...</div>
<div id="risk-free-info-div" class="popupbox">...my friend over here</div>
```

Once it's done it works with no flickering - see the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y8Ptn/) that I created here.